# How to set specific property in mongo document incremently using $inc? If property does not exist in document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am running a utility to update all documents. I don't know what am I doing wrong in the code. Here is my code.

```
let userId = userIds.pop();
let allMembers = await Member.find({ userId: userId }).lean();
allMembers = allMembers.map((obj) => obj._id);
await Member.updateMany({ _id: { $in: allMembers } }, { $inc: { index: 1 } });
```

the index does not exist in my document.

Looking for a solution!

Comment: Do you get an error? What results do you get? What does a document look like and how do you want it modified?

Comment: I did not get any error, but all the documents got updated with index = 1

Comment: As per the [Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/#behavior) - if the field doesn't exist it will create the field with the value specified (as you are seeing). Since that isn't what you want (right?) - what do you want?

Comment: Yes, I read the docs. Anyway, I found another way to do it. Thanks for the quick response.